# Copying data from one row to another in the same table SQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm having a hard time copying data from one row to another in the same table. Basically, I have a case where the column `[I/O#]` equals `'Client1'` but I would like to make the `[I/O#]` column equal to `'Client2'` without having the data attributed to Client1 erased, i.e. I want to keep the data associated with `Client1` but just replace the name to `Client2`.

I attempted the following sql query in my php file but in vain :

```
$sql_UPDATE_query ="UPDATE [$connectionInfo[Database]].[dbo].[form_record]
                    SET
                        [Last_Edit] = newdata.[Last_Edit],
                        [User_Name] = newdata.[User_Name],
                        [Computer_Name] = newdata.[Computer_Name],
                        [form_name] = newdata.[form_name],
                        [Date] = newdata.[Date],
                        [facility] = newdata.[facility],
                        [Count] = newdata.[Count],
                        [Start_Time] = newdata.[Start_Time],
                        [Stop_Time] = newdata.[Stop_Time],
                        [MW/Hrs_Start] = newdata.[MW/Hrs_Start],
                        [MW/Hrs_Stop] = newdata.[MW/Hrs_Stop],
                        [M³] = newdata.[M³],
                        [MCF] = newdata.[MCF],
                        [Litres] = newdata.[Litres],
                        [Description] = newdata.[Description],
                        [Lock] = newdata.[Lock]
                    FROM
                        (
                        SELECT
                            [Last_Edit],
                            [User_Name],
                            [Computer_Name],
                            [form_name],
                            [Date],
                            [facility],
                            [Count],
                            [Start_Time],
                            [Stop_Time],
                            [MW/Hrs_Start],
                            [MW/Hrs_Stop],
                            [M³],
                            [MCF],
                            [Litres],
                            [Description],
                            [Lock]
                        FROM [$connectionInfo[Database]].[dbo].[form_record]
                        WHERE
                            [I/O#] = '$PrevIO'
                        ) newdata
                    WHERE
                        [I/O#] = '$IO'";
```

By the way `$PrevIO` and `$IO` are already defined in my php file (just not showing it) so that's not where the error lies.

Now, let's say `$PrevIO='Client1'` and `$IO='Client2`. How can I attribute all the data (row) in table `[form_record]` that belongs to Client1 and copy it to Client2 and then eventually delete Client1 or even better, simply replace simply the name but you guys know better. I thought that `newdata` could be used as an alias table for the same table `form_record` but it seems like it doesn't work.

*I'm using Microsoft SQL 2005 Server.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should do it, you only need to include the proper join in the table.

```
$sql_UPDATE_query ="UPDATE UPD
                    SET
                        [Last_Edit] = newdata.[Last_Edit],
                        [User_Name] = newdata.[User_Name],
                        [Computer_Name] = newdata.[Computer_Name],
                        [form_name] = newdata.[form_name],
                        [Date] = newdata.[Date],
                        [facility] = newdata.[facility],
                        [Count] = newdata.[Count],
                        [Start_Time] = newdata.[Start_Time],
                        [Stop_Time] = newdata.[Stop_Time],
                        [MW/Hrs_Start] = newdata.[MW/Hrs_Start],
                        [MW/Hrs_Stop] = newdata.[MW/Hrs_Stop],
                        [M³] = newdata.[M³],
                        [MCF] = newdata.[MCF],
                        [Litres] = newdata.[Litres],
                        [Description] = newdata.[Description],
                        [Lock] = newdata.[Lock]
                    FROM [$connectionInfo[Database]].[dbo].[form_record] UPD
                    INNER JOIN 
                        (
                        SELECT
                            [Last_Edit],
                            [User_Name],
                            [Computer_Name],
                            [form_name],
                            [Date],
                            [facility],
                            [Count],
                            [Start_Time],
                            [Stop_Time],
                            [MW/Hrs_Start],
                            [MW/Hrs_Stop],
                            [M³],
                            [MCF],
                            [Litres],
                            [Description],
                            [Lock]
                        FROM [$connectionInfo[Database]].[dbo].[form_record]
                        WHERE
                            [I/O#] = '$PrevIO'
                        ) newdata ON ***newdata.field = UPD.field***
                    WHERE
                        [I/O#] = '$IO'";
```

Comment: Yes, you need to replace `***newdata.field = UPD.field***` with your condition.

Answer (score 0):

your `join condition` is missing :

```
$sql_UPDATE_query ="UPDATE A
                    SET
                        [Last_Edit] = newdata.[Last_Edit],
                        [User_Name] = newdata.[User_Name],
                        [Computer_Name] = newdata.[Computer_Name],
                        [form_name] = newdata.[form_name],
                        [Date] = newdata.[Date],
                        [facility] = newdata.[facility],
                        [Count] = newdata.[Count],
                        [Start_Time] = newdata.[Start_Time],
                        [Stop_Time] = newdata.[Stop_Time],
                        [MW/Hrs_Start] = newdata.[MW/Hrs_Start],
                        [MW/Hrs_Stop] = newdata.[MW/Hrs_Stop],
                        [M³] = newdata.[M³],
                        [MCF] = newdata.[MCF],
                        [Litres] = newdata.[Litres],
                        [Description] = newdata.[Description],
                        [Lock] = newdata.[Lock]
                    FROM [$connectionInfo[Database]].[dbo].[form_record] A
                    INNER JOIN 
                        (
                        SELECT
                            [Last_Edit],
                            [User_Name],
                            [Computer_Name],
                            [form_name],
                            [Date],
                            [facility],
                            [Count],
                            [Start_Time],
                            [Stop_Time],
                            [MW/Hrs_Start],
                            [MW/Hrs_Stop],
                            [M³],
                            [MCF],
                            [Litres],
                            [Description],
                            [Lock]
                        FROM [$connectionInfo[Database]].[dbo].[form_record]
                        WHERE
                            [I/O#] = '$PrevIO'
                        ) newdata ON newdata.field = A.field
                    WHERE
                        [I/O#] = '$IO'";
```